# How to link 2 different post types programatically

Tags: custom-post-types

I've created 2 custom post type: Course and Tutor:

```
<?php
/*** Registering Course post type ***/
function px_course() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'               => 'courses',
    'singular_name'      => 'course',
    'menu_name'          => 'courses',
  );

  $args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'course' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields' )
  );

  register_post_type( 'course', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'px_course' );

/*** Registering Tutor post type ***/
function px_tutor() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'               => 'tutor',
    'singular_name'      => 'tutor',
    'menu_name'          => 'tutor',
  );

  $args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'tutor' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields' )
  );

  register_post_type( 'tutor', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'px_tutor' );
?>
```

and I have a custom field in the course post type that is asking the user to put the link to the page of the course tutor. I'm looking for a way to do this part programmatically. Say I have three course: PHP, CSS, and Javascript and also two tutor: Alex and Todd.

Alex and Todd each has a page created using tutor custom post type with their info: facebook profile, e-maill and ... I want to link to them in the course page if they are tutor of that course. How can I do it programatically?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't be creating `tutor` custom post type for this. Just a make new role `tutor` and assign to every user who is going to be a tutor. Then edit `author.php` and display content based on role `tutor`. For binding Alex and Todd with a course, you have to add custom field containing, the ids of authors, in that specific `course` post.

Comment: Thank you but I want it to be completely customizable. I want to have a tutor custom post type so that visitors can look at their pages. With roles, I should say I'm not a fan of them! I need a CPT for tutors.

Comment: It should be easy to link the CPTs with post meta but I agree with the previous comment. Logically, your tutors are a role.

Comment: @pershianix You have the ability to fully customize `author.php` based on the role. If you can also add custom user meta of your choice for each user. It's not about being fan of something, it's about the standardized approach.

Comment: You're right if I want to have authors but the only author of the site is me and tutors are just some people that teach courses and they have nothing to do with the site. So how can I use roles for them? Or maybe I'm wrong about something.